# Closed form for $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots}}}}$

Tags: infinite-product, nested-radicals

Closed form for $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots}}}}$

This is equivalent to $\prod_{n=1}^\infty n^{1/2^n}$.

Putting this into Wolframalpha gives that it is approximately 1.661687, and failed to find a closed form.

(1) Is this irrational and transcendental, irrational and algebraic, or rational?

(2) Is there a name for this constant or does there exist a possible closed form?

(3) How does one calculate its partial sum formula? [Wolfram Partialsum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=prod%28n%3D1%20to%20infinity%29%20%28n%5E%281%2F2%5En%29%29)

Comment: Putting that number into a search engine gives [this](http://books.google.de/books?id=TySkMs-B_JkC&pg=PA24&lpg=PA24&dq=1.661687&source=bl&ots=lRUtkqAVem&sig=A2T3fSb0KnGAtvav5gThAcTpAG0&hl=de&sa=X&ei=u2OGVK_JKNfvarXAgcgF&ved=0CD8Q6AEwCTgK#v=onepage&q=1.661687&f=false) or [this](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/3620590?uid=3737864&uid=2460338175&uid=2460337935&uid=2&uid=4&uid=83&uid=63&sid=21105412536073).

Comment: The second link is merely the same question as this one, just with a log taken to make the product a sum. The first link does not match with the value given.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a name for it. It is called the [Somos' Quadratic Recurrence Constant](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SomossQuadraticRecurrenceConstant.html). It has a weird closed-form in terms of the *polylogarithm* and *Lerch transcendent*.

**P.S.** You can search for constants in the OEIS using its decimal expansion. If you're lucky, then it might be there like in this case: [1,6,6,1,6,8,](https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C6%2C6%2C1%2C6%2C8%2C&language=english&go=Search) (A112302)

Comment: Sigh, did you look at the definition of https://oeis.org/A112302? It is precisely $\sqrt{1\sqrt{2\sqrt{3\sqrt{4\cdots}}}}$

Comment: Wolfram may be wrong. Check out the Mathworld Link.

Comment: Wolfram alpha and mathematica are not infallible.

Comment: Is it irrational and transcendental? Mathworld does not have a notice on that.

Comment: @MathNoob:  We are pretty sure it is transcendental, but probably don't have a proof.  Unless a number has a reason to be algebraic, it is transcendental-there are only countably many algebraic numbers.  This doesn't seem to have a reason to be algebraic.

Comment: @RossMillikan Although this argument is often used (also for irrationality or normality) , we should not claim a number to be XY if we cannot prove it (just because we cannot determine a minimal polynomial). Upto some degree , we can find a lower bound for the absolute value of the coefficients of a possible minimal polynomial , if this is high upto a high degree, we have "a good chance" to have a transcendental number.

Comment: Moreover, the constant problem might prevent us to establish the given number to be algebraic , should this actually be the case.

Answer (score 4):

Let $$A=\prod_{n=1}^\infty n^{1/2^n}$$ $$\log(A)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n}\log(n)$$ and, from a CAS, the result is $$\log(A)=-\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ $$A=e^{-\text{PolyLog}^{(1,0)}\left(0,\frac{1}{2}\right)}$$ where appears a derivative of the polylogarithm function.